# Algorithm seems to only work on last chunk of ArrayList

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

The goal of this algorithm is to take a list of strings and abbreviate them in such a way that they can uniquely identify the word they represent, this is a homework assignment.
The algorithm I've tried to create for this problem searches the substrings for any possible matches, although it seemed that a trie would be more effective for this solution, I couldn't seem to wrap my head aroud how the code for one works; that being said, it should still be very possible to do it this way as well.
Input: ~~~~~~~~~~~  Expected Output: ~~~~~~~~~~~~ Actual Output:
carbohydrate -------- carboh -------------------------------- carbohydrate
cart -------------------- cart ------------------------------------ cart
carburetor ------------ carbu --------------------------------- carburetor
caramel --------------- cara ----------------------------------- caramel
caribou --------------- cari ------------------------------------- caribou
carbonic -------------- carboni -------------------------------- carbonic
cartilage -------------- carti ------------------------------------ cartilage
carbon ---------------- carbon --------------------------------- carbon
carriage -------------- carriage -------------------------------- carr
carton ----------------- carto ----------------------------------- carto
car --------------------- car ------------------------------------- car
carbonate ------------ carbona ------------------------------- carbona

This here is the actual code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ShortestPrefixes
{

    ArrayList<String> characterCounter = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean isEqual = false;

    public static ArrayList testArrayList()
    {
        ArrayList<String> testArray = new ArrayList<>();
        testArray.add("carbohydrate");
        testArray.add("cart");
        testArray.add("carburetor");
        testArray.add("caramel");
        testArray.add("caribou");
        testArray.add("carbonic");
        testArray.add("cartilage");
        testArray.add("carbon");
        testArray.add("carriage");
        testArray.add("carton");
        testArray.add("car");
        testArray.add("carbonate");
        return testArray;

    }
    public ArrayList getShortestPrefixes(ArrayList<String> input)
    {
        ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println(input.size());
        for (int count = 0; count<input.size(); count++) //This loop counts which word is being reduced
        {
            //System.out.println(count);
            String word = input.get(count);
            //System.out.println(word);
            for (int compare = 0; compare<input.size(); compare++)//this loop counts the characters of the word being reduced
            {

                    if(input.get(compare) .equals(word)){}

                        isEqual=false;
                        ArrayList<String> wordBeingComparedRightNow = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (int searchCount = 0; searchCount<input.get(searchCount).length(); searchCount++)//this loop compares the string to every possible substring
                        {
                            wordBeingComparedRightNow.clear();
                            String wordAboutToBeCompared = input.get(searchCount);
                            wordBeingComparedRightNow.add(wordAboutToBeCompared);

                            for (int miniLoop = 0; miniLoop<input.get(searchCount).length()-1; miniLoop++)//this loop sets up for a word's substrings to be tested
                            {
                                wordAboutToBeCompared = wordAboutToBeCompared.substring(0, wordAboutToBeCompared.length() -1);
                                wordBeingComparedRightNow.add(wordAboutToBeCompared);

                            }

                            for(int variableName = 0; variableName < wordBeingComparedRightNow.size(); variableName++)//this word compares the array craeated in the last step with the substring we currently have
                            {
                                if(wordBeingComparedRightNow.get(variableName) .equals(word.substring(0, word.length()-1)))
                                {
                                    isEqual=true;
                                }

                            }
                        }
                            if (!isEqual)
                            {
                            System.out.println(word);
                            word = word.substring(0, word.length()-1);
                            }

            }
            //System.out.println(word);
            output.add(word);

        }

        System.out.println(testArrayList());
        return output;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ShortestPrefixes sp = new ShortestPrefixes();
        ArrayList<String> output = sp.getShortestPrefixes(testArrayList());
        System.out.println(output);

    }

}
```

I think the problem is somewhere within the second for loop, but I can't quite figure out where; if anyone could identify why my algorithm doesn't work or at least point me in the right direction; I'd really appreciate it.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of `if(input.get(compare) .equals(word)){}` ?

Comment: And how do you get this mapping `carbohydrate -------- carboh -------------------------------- carbohydrate` where carboh as you expect is not in the input?

Comment: The if(input.get(compare) .equals(word){} was something I was using to try and debug my code by forcing the loop to continue(); but I removed that at some point which left it as garbage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well what you are trying to do, for each word you try to find the shortest prefix starting with the longest one.

Then you check if the next prefix (the current one minus one character) is equals to some of the all possible substrings of the other words.
*Note that you are also comparing the prefix with the current word substrings, you need to skip the current word in this comparison.*

If next prefix is unique, then it becomes the current one: `word.substring(0, word.length()-1)`
The process should be repeated until you can not find a shorter prefix that is unique.

But this `for` is very strange:

```
for (int searchCount = 0; searchCount < input.get(searchCount).length(); searchCount++)
```

you iterate over `searchCount` but it's part of both sides of the end condition. So the end condition  is different for each iteration.

Since this is homework, I'll propose you another approach I think is more easy. The idea is to start with single-letter prefixes and enlarge them until all are valid.

```
Step 0:
    input <- [carbohydrate, cart, carburetor, caramel, caribou, carbonic, cartilage, carbon, carriage, carton, car, carbonate]
    output <- [ , , , , , , , , , , , ]

Step 1: 
    For each prefix in output check if it's valid. (*1) If not then add one more char to it. 

Step 2:   
    If some prefix was not valid, the go to step 1.

(*1) A prefix is valid if one of the folling conditions occurs: Prefix is unique in output or you cannot add more chars prefix == word
```

*HINT* For each iteration the output is:

```
Iteration 0: [, , , , , , , , , , , ]
Iteration 1: [c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c]
Iteration 2: [ca, ca, ca, ca, ca, ca, ca, ca, ca, ca, ca, ca]
Iteration 3: [car, car, car, car, car, car, car, car, car, car, car, car]
Iteration 4: [carb, cart, carb, cara, cari, carb, cart, carb, carr, cart, car, carb]
Iteration 5: [carbo, cart, carbu, cara, cari, carbo, carti, carbo, carr, carto, car, carbo]
Iteration 6: [carboh, cart, carbu, cara, cari, carbon, carti, carbon, carr, carto, car, carbon]
Iteration 7: [carboh, cart, carbu, cara, cari, carboni, carti, carbon, carr, carto, car, carbona]
```

Try it. I tested it with a small implementation. But as this is homework I do not think I should give you the code directly ;) If you get stuck, post a comment.

**Pseudocode**

```
// Step 0: Initialize input and output

input <- [carbohydrate, cart, carburetor, caramel, caribou, carbonic, cartilage, carbon, carriage, carton, car, carbonate]
output <- [ , , , , , , , , , , , ]

allFound <- false; // Helper variable to know if all prefixes are valid

while (not allFound) { // Step 2 Iteration: until all prefixes are ok

    // For simplicity, we first count the occurrences of each prefix
    for each prefix in output {
        prefixCount[prefix] <- prefixCount[prefix] + 1 // You may use a Map for this 
    }

    // Step 1: For each prefix check if is valid, if not add one more char
    allFound <- true; 
    for (i = 0; i < output size; i++) {
        if not (prefixCount[prefix] == 1 /* is unique */ OR output[i] is equals input[i]) {
            // Prefix is not ok                
            output[i] <- output[i] + next char form input[i]; // Add one more char
            allFound <- false; // Step 2 iteration condition "some prefix is not valid"
        }       
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and the help, this is precisely what I'm trying to do. I've run into a problem trying your approach, I'm not really sure how I can utilize my loops for this to reach the desired outcome. I have a for loop that loops for each string in the input arraylist, and a while loop that loops through a single string. I'm just not sure what I should be doing.

Comment: @Thraktor Edited my answer. I've simplified the algorithm (sure can be optimized) and added a pseudocode with the main idea. You only need two loop level.

Comment: I've run into one other issue, I think that what I wrote from the pseudo code for that for each loop doesn't work, I've gotten two scenarios; either the array prefixCount just increases in size repeatedly, or every value gets set to one, depending on where I declare it. I wrote it as a regular for loop because I wasn't sure of the syntax of a for each loop; is that a problem?

Comment: For each loop is essentially equivalent to a regular for. That is not the problem. Look at this implementation http://ideone.com/ytznr6

Comment: Thanks for the help, my issue earlier was that I misunderstood what was meant by "count the occurences of each prefix" in the pseudo code.